# Click Once - Cannot Add Shortcut As a Resource to Deploy

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, clickonce, publishing

I'm trying to add a shortcut to be deployed with my OneClick application. The problem is that whenever I add it as a resource Visual Studio adds the file it POINTS to instead of the actual shortcut to the file. Is there any way around this? I've Googled around to no avail but I might be using the wrong key words.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution I received from MSDN-

> I suggest you add the shortcut in the following method.
>
> Step 1: you could copy the shortcut to your project folder.
>
> Step 2: click the "show All files" icon in the Solution Explorer(like
>   the following picture), find the shortcut.Ink file, then right-click
>   on it, choose the "Include In Project".
>
> Step 3: Set the "Build Action" property to "Content", Set the "Copy to
>   Output Directory" to "Copy always"
>
> Step 4: Run your application, then publish it. you could find the
>   shortcut in the Application Files.
>
> If you have any other concern regarding this issue, please feel free
>   to let me know.